# MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["game"]
mycol = mydb["test_collection"]


class ProcessWork:
    res1 = []
    res2 = []

    def processwork1(request, res1):
        country = request.GET.get('country')
        qry = {'country': country}
        query = mycol.find(qry).limit(10)
        result = json.loads(dumps(query))
        res1.append(result)

    def processwork2(request, res2):
        country = request.GET.get('country')
        qry = {'country': country}
        query = mycol.find(qry).skip(10).limit(10)
        result = json.loads(dumps(query))
        res2.append(result)

    def process(request):
        t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=ProcessWork.processwork1, args=((request), ProcessWork.res1))
        t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=ProcessWork.processwork1, args=((request), ProcessWork.res2))

        t1.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.start()
        t2.join()
        # result = ProcessWork.res1[0] + ProcessWork.res2[0]
        return JsonResponse({})
```

errors in terminal:

```
    /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/cache/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py:150: UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for details: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe
      "MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only "
    /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/cache/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py:150: UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for details: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe
      "MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only "
```

Here i am runnning multiple task in python using multiprocessing.
I am fetching data from mongodb using pymongo client.

I am not able to understand this errror.
Because of this result i am not getting result also.

Please have a look

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and would love if you could share your solution with us

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating your Mongo connection inside the `processwork2()` and `processwork1()` methods?

You are creating your MongoClient before the `fork()` system call happens (probably part of the creation of the new process by OS).

just put this part inside the method body:

```python
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["game"]
mycol = mydb["test_collection"]
```